# Sistema de cronómetros JS y PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, timer

Se me ha pedido realizar un sistema de control de tiempos mediante cronómetros, es decir, existe una tabla que muestra a los usuarios registrados, a cada tabla le corresponde un cronómetro con los botones Iniciar, Pausar y Resetear, esto para que un grupo de personas pueda ver dicha tabla e ir llevando el control de los tiempos con el uso de los cronómetros.

La tabla obtiene los usuarios desde una base de datos PHP y se inserta en el arreglo el cronómetro de modo que aparezca en cada una de las filas un cronómetro individual que funcione para dicha fila.

El problema recae en que, un la página no se visualizan los botones que controlan los cronómetros, esto los hace inutilizables y no me permite comprobar la funcionalidad del sistema.

Cabe recalcar que, además, es necesario que los cronometros puedan funcionar aún cuando nadie esté viendo dicha página, para que el tiempo del personal siga corriendo, y que los tiempos pausados sigan mostrando su acumulado aunque la página se recargue.

Adjunto código:

```
<table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>ID</th>
                          <th>Usuario</th>
                          <th>Cronómetro</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($query as $fila): ?>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <?php echo $fila['id']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <?php echo $fila['user']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <div id="cronometro-<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>"></div>
                              <script>
                                var interval<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>;
                                var tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> = 0;
                                var ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> = '';

                                function actualizarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>() {
                                  tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>++;
                                  var horas = Math.floor(tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> / 3600);
                                  var minutos = Math.floor((tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> - (horas * 3600)) / 60);
                                  var segundos = tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> - (horas * 3600) - (minutos * 60);
                                  var tiempo = horas.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + minutos.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + segundos.toString().padStart(2, '0');
                                  document.getElementById("cronometro-<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>").innerHTML = tiempo;
                                }

                                function iniciarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>() {
                                  if (ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> == 'pausa') {
                                    tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>'));
                                  } else {
                                    tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> = 0;
                                  }
                                  interval<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> = setInterval(function () {
                                    actualizarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>();
                                  }, 1000);
                                  ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> = 'iniciar';
                                  localStorage.setItem('ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>', ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>);
                                }

                                function pausarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>() {
                                  clearInterval(interval<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>);
                                  ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> = 'pausa';
                                  localStorage.setItem('ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>', ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>);
                                  localStorage.setItem('tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>', tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>);
                                }

                                function reiniciarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>() {
                                  clearInterval(interval<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>);
                                  tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> = 0;
                                  actualizarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>();
                                  ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> = 'reiniciar';
                                  localStorage.setItem('ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>', ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>);
                                  localStorage.setItem('tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>', tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>);
                                }

                                // Cargar estado del cronometro al cargar la pagina
                                ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> = localStorage.getItem('ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>');
                                if (ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> == 'iniciar') {
                                  iniciarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>();
                                } else if (ultimoBoton<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> == 'pausa') {
                                  actualizarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>();
                                  tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?> = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('tiempoActual<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>'));
                                } else {
                                  reiniciarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>();
                                }
                              </script>
                              <button onclick="iniciarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>()">Iniciar</button>
                              <button onclick="pausarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>()">Pausar</button>
                              <button onclick="reiniciarCronometro<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>()">Reiniciar</button>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mucho texto que diria mi hijo... se que es dificil concretar código cuando no tienes experiencia pero es una gran habilidad para conseguir respuestas.

Veo demasiados problemas en tu pregunta, te recomiento volver a empezar de 0 e ir añadiendo partes poco a poco para asegurarte de que funcionan y detectar el punto en el que se rompe algo, te orientará y nos simplificará las cosas.

Trata de mostrar solo los botones a ver que pasa.
Estás recibiendo mensajes de error? si es que no, provoca uno y si no se muestra ninguno, haz que se muestren.

En lo que si que te puedo orientar un poco es en esto

> Cabe recalcar que, además, es necesario que los cronometros puedan funcionar aún cuando nadie esté viendo dicha página, para que el tiempo del personal siga corriendo, y que los tiempos pausados sigan mostrando su acumulado aunque la página se recargue.

hay una cosa que se llama unix timestamp

> El tiempo Epoch es la hora actual medida en número de segundos desde el Epoch Unix. Epoch 0 es enero 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT

lo genial de eso es que ya tienes una forma comoda de almacenar un punto en el tiempo, muchos lenguajes te lo dan incluso con milisegundos.

Cada vez que inicies un cronometro deberás almacenar de alguna manera su timestamp de inicio, y asi cuando cualquiera quiera volver a el, tendrás una referencia desde la que partir para calcular los siguientes tiempos

Comment: Muchas gracias, probaré con tus indicaciones.